# Facebook likebox event on clicking button

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, api, sdk

I'm trying to use SDK Facebook to detect the click on the button "like" of the likebox and call a function , but it not working .
Here's my code :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    </body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'xxxx', // App ID
      channelURL : 'xxxx/facebook/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
        alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
    }
);
</script>

<fb:like-box href="http://www.facebook.com/MarwenClubiiste" width="292" show_faces="false" stream="false" header="false"></fb:like-box>

</html>
```

Please Help , I really need this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like box has a known bug, where the edge.create event doesn't work if the user is logged out of facebook and has to login to LIKE the page.
However it works fine if the user is already logged in.
Here is a mention of this bug :

https://github.com/facebook/connect-js/issues/82

http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=75166

The Like button does not have this bug, and fires the event in both cases.
You may have to replace the LikeBox with a Like button + some custom HTML of your own.

Try using non-async loading of facebook JS as well . Here is more help :

http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=87926